# Node.js Logging to a external website from code. (osmosis , cheerio)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, electron, cheerio

I am writing an **electron** app which connects with an external site.
and i found out , cheerio can't scrape sites which needs to be logged in . so i am using osmosis now but it's showing following error .

`(get) loaded [get] https://somesite.com/
(find) found 1 results for "#login-form"
(login) No login form found`

where the code is

```
osmosis
.get("https://somesite.com")
.find("#login- 
 form").login("mailid","password","login 
 sucess","login failed")
.set({
 div: 'div',
 title: 'title'
})
.log(console.log)
.debug(console.log)
.error(console.log);
```

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Use without .find("#login-form")